# JavaScript change class with select form

Tags: javascript

I need a select form that will change the class of a div element. From the sample code below, how can I use JavaScript to change the class of div(myBox) depending on the selection.

```
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <style type="text/css"> 
    .red {background:#FF0000;color:#FFF} 
    .white {background:#FFF;color:#000} 
    .blue {background:#0000FF;color:#FFF} 
    </style> 
    </head> 

    <body> 
    <form id="myform" action="#"> 
    <select id="bgcolor"> 
        <option value="red">Red</option> 
        <option value="white">White</option> 
        <option value="blue">Blue</option> 
    </select> 
    </form> 

    <div id="myBox" class="red">This is myBox</div> 

    </body> 
    </html>
```

Comment: There is a question there, but I think perhaps what @Ingenu meant is [what have you tried already?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) (As it stands now you don't seem to be asking for help with a problem so much as asking us to implement the whole thing for you.)

Answer (score 1):

Handle the `onchange` event of the `select element` and change the `class` of the `div`:

```
document.getElementById('bgcolor').onchange = function(){
    document.getElementById('myBox').className = this.value;
};
```

Comment: Simpler and perhaps more obvious as `document.getElementById('myBox').className = this.value;`. Navigating select options using keys in IE will give interesting results. :-)